# おすすめ品 on Doujins in Akihabara

Tags: manga

I have seen おすすめ品 written on stickers on doujins in Akihabara. In one shop this was literally on every single doujin. From what I know おすすめ品 means recommended goods, which makes no sense here, as its on every product... Does おすすめ品 have a specific meaning here?

Comment: There are a furniture store and a shoe store in my neighborhood that have been holding 閉店セール several times a year and for over 20 years. ♡

Comment: Reminds me of 大好評発売中, also written on nearly everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as meaning goes, it simply means "recommended (item)" and nothing more. It's a common business practice and you don't have to take it seriously.